# Flutter web code when i compile for android devices

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter 3.0
I have a widget with a button that is displayed only on web platform

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
...

                  kIsWeb ? SizedBox(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 55.0,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Color(0xFF124B92),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                ),
                                child: const Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'DOWNLOAD',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                      Uint8List? imageBytes =
                                        await screenshotController.capture();
                                    
                                      final blob = html.Blob([imageBytes]);
                                      final url =
                                          html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
                                      final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
                                        ..target = 'blank'
                                        ..download = "a.png";
                                      anchor.click();
                                }
                                ),
                          )
                        : SizedBox()
                  ]),
```

When i run this code on web platform always is ok. If i compile on Android devices it return the error

```
Error: Method not found: 'Blob'
Error: Undefined name 'Url'
Method not found: 'AnchorElement'
```

How can i prevent of compile this code when I'm using an Android or OSx platform?

Thanks